# Alternatives to Flow for javascript

Tags: types

Are there any alternative type checkers to Facebook's flow?

PS. I'm not sure how to expand on this question, and search and google do not bring anything up.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/ is the main alternative

Comment: there is also purescript, js++, dart, reasonml

Answer (score 1):

In terms of writing plain-old JavaScript code with type annotations, Flow is technically the only option.

There are, however, a number of languages that compile down to JavaScript such as [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/), [PureScript](http://www.purescript.org/), [ReasonML](https://reasonml.github.io/), [Elm](https://elm-lang.org/), and [Fable](https://fable.io/)

Of these, TypeScript is almost identical to JavaScript aside from the fact that it requires using `.ts` and `.tsx` file extensions rather than `.js` and `.jsx`. TypeScript also [recently announced support for transpilation/compilation using Babel](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/08/27/typescript-and-babel-7/) so you can use your existing build process